# WordPress update 4.4.1 redirect loop

Tags: redirect, updates

I have updated the WordPress site from 4.2.9 to 4.4.1 today. Now, after update the home page is going into redirect loop. The inner pages/posts , admin dashboard and all works fine. Only issue is with homepage.

Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean with a redirect loop.

Comment: @PieterGoosen The browser returns the error  'This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'

Comment: Then you have some code in a theme or a plugin which handles some kind of redirection. You need to find that. Disbable plugins and switch to a bundled theme and recheck

Answer (score 0):

There is number of possible way to coming this issue with message "*net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*". I list some of them:

**1.** File/Folder permission issue
Check and changed the permissions of wp-login.php to 644, if the WordPress login page has this issue.

After this, another redirect loop? So, once again, looking at /wp-admin/index.php, the permissions were 664 rather than 644.

You can check more about Permission Scheme for WordPress(https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

**2.** Url without www.
You need to check and changed the siteurl and home options (option_name column) in [wp-prefix]_options table from "http://example.com" to "http://www.example.com" if it require.

**3.** Affected by external plugin use
Please check this by rename your every external plugin folder and rollback if it show up one by one.

**4.** Regenerate you .htaccess by paste code from Options -> Permalinks
Also make sure everything is in lowercase.

Hope you can find your solution from this.